# How to list all the users belonging to the current application, not the current account in QuickBlox for IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, quickblox

I'm using the Quick Blox ios SDK. I have created two apps in the QuickBlox dashboard. While listing the users in the application its showing all the users belonging to my account[users of both the apps], not the users of the current application.

How can I list the users belonging to any particular application created in my account in QuickBlox.

Answer (score 0):

There is a checkbox named **Show only application users**

Comment: Not in the dashboard,its listing all the users in the application.

Comment: Okay, you can use tags, just set tag when registering user and then retrieve users by tags